# Finding a basis for a diagonalized quadratic form.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have taken a Quadratic form and performed simultaneous row and column operations on it.  I started with $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1\\2 & 3 & 4\\ 1 & 4 & 5\end{pmatrix}$$ and diagonalized to $$D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 8\end{pmatrix} S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\-2 & 1 & 0 \\ -5 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ where $SAS^T = D$.  How do I find the new basis for the diagonalized version of A?

EDIT:  I typed A incorrectly.

Comment: First of all, $SAS^T$ (with transpose) is only ok if $S$ is orthonormal. Secondly, in the form $A=S^{-1}DS$, rows of $S$ are the basis.

Comment: Rows of S are the basis, not the columns?

Comment: Also, is in not the columns of $S$ for $S^{-1}AS = D$ form the basis of D?

Comment: It depends on how you write it. If you write $A=S^{-1}DS$, then $Av=S^{-1}DSv$ and $Sv$ does dot products between rows of $S$ and the vector $v$. This means rows of $S$ are the contravariant basis of $A$ and columns of $S^{-1}$ are the covariant basis. If $S^{-1}=S^T$ then the left and right eigenvectors are the same. If you instead write $A=SDS^{-1}$, it's the other way around. Also, be careful, you are writing $D$ in terms of $A$, so everything is reversed once again.

Comment: Some of the terminology that you used, such as contravariant and covariant, I have never seen before.  How do I go about solving for $S$ such that the rows are the basis?  I know from simple calculations that $S^{-1}$ does not equal $S^T$.  This was an example in lecture and the professor worked to this point and said that it is easy/obvious what the basis is.

Comment: $S^T=S^{-1}$ would only be true, if rows/columns were orthogonal and normalized. The most standard way is to write $A=SDS^{-1}$, then columns of $S$ are the basis. As for the rest, you did something wrong. Your form is symmetric, which automatically means that $S$ should be orthogonal (which means $S^T=S^{-1}$ and left and right eigenvectors are the same, so you don't need all that stuff I was talking about).

Comment: I went back through my notes and recalculated $D$ and $S$.  I got the same thing again.  I can confirm that $SAS^T = D$.